# Как увеличить размер QWidget за пределы Parent Widget

Tags: c++, qt

```
QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget(pParent);
```

Когда увеличиваешь размер виджета то не выходит за пределы родителя
А если не даешь указатель на родителя то нормально выходит за пределы но тогда не работают события (mouse events)
Мне нужно создать custom widget чтобы мог дать указатель на родителя но изменять его размеры за пределы родителя 
floating widget

Comment: вопрос написан весьма невнятно.

Comment: не получится. Для того, чтобы он был отдельным виджетом, указатель на родителья должен иметь нулевое значение

Comment: тогда mouse events не работают

Answer (score 0):

`setWindowsFlag(Qt::Popup);` решает проблему